# How to scroll down a custom div based scrollbar using javascript

Tags: javascript, imacros

I'm trying to capture multiple screenshots automatically using iMacros plugin in firefox. The page that I'm trying to capture the screenshot contains a vertical scrollable sidebar. I want to trigger scrolling to capture all the content within the sidebar. The scrollbar used is a custom one based on div and not the browser default. So how do I trigger scrolling?

The code below doesn't seems to work:

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementsByClassName('scrollContents').scrollTop = 10;
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="captionFileBody" class="scrollWrapper" >
    <div class="scrollBar ">
        <div class="scrollBarUpArrow"></div>
        <div class="scrollBarHandle"></div>
        <div class="scrollBarDownArrow"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="scrollContents">Content comes here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function doScroll() {
   var el = document.querySelector('.scrollContents');
   el.scrollTop = '900';
}
```

Then call that function what ever You like. It should do the trick. [Check CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oWzWxr)